# How does the memory stores the bits?

Tags: binary, logic, computer-science, cpu-architecture, ram

In the last lecture we discussed logic gates and binary system.
We discussed flip flops and a lot of types.
Now I'm confused about memory structure, it is a billions of flip flops gates that stores billions of 0s and 1s, or what?  How exactly the memory stores bits?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Stackoverflow is for programming questions. General understanding questions like yours can be better answered with a text book, on wikipedia, or with a web search.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). When asking a question context is important; that first sentence about last lecture is very confusing out of context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best place to learn about this is the classic [What every programmer should know about memory](https://lwn.net/Articles/250967/), that is [still discussed as good source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126311/what-every-programmer-should-know-about-memory).

But long story short yes, it's like billions of gates. It seems overwhelming (and it is), but the modularization - in itself a great concept - allows you to think in levels of cells, then rows, then other abstractions, so a high-level developer don't need to know about this in order to get software working. For the hardware designer it is equally important: you build a component, abstract it, build a higher level component, and so on.

Comment: Yes, Ulrich Drepper's article is still a good description of DRAM (and cache SRAM).  But no, DRAM isn't billions of *gates*, it's billions of *capacitors* with a grid of row/column lines driven by transistors.  (e.g. reading involves a "sense amplifier".)  That's *why* it's *dynamic* and needs to be refreshed frequently.